# Elegant solution to class design

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have following design problem programming application in **C#.**

I have classes **A** and **B** that both **derives from C**. I cannot change theirs definition because they are defined in **external assembly** and are **not** defined as **partial** too.

What I am trying to achieve is to differ functionality basing on weather provided **C object** is of type ***A or B***. Of course I dont want to use if statements comparing runtime types of provided object. Is it possible with **extensions methods?** I dont think so.
Any solution? :)

Comment: Please show what you have got so far and why that doesn't comply with your demands.

Comment: Why do you need to know if C is an A or B?

Comment: How do you get/create instances of A and B? Do you `new` them or are they created via some type of Factory method?

Comment: I do not create them. Lets assume that they are given to me.

Comment: Once they are given to you do they remain in existance, are they long-lived?  Or are these objects passed to you to act upon within a method as a param and then they go out of scope?

Comment: Theese objects are exceptions in fact but this does not matter. Lets assume that problem is general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the answer. 
The dynamic keyword is the clue here.
We can write:

```
void Handle(C c)
{
   dynamic cc = c;  
   HandleSpecific(cc);   
}
void HandleSpecific(A a)
{
//Specific behavior A
}
void HandleSpecific(B b)
{
//Specific behavior B
}
```

Drawbacks are of course - Risk of exception beacause of runtime binding introduced here and slight performance hit.

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible with extension methods by using generics.
Multiple approaches are possible, but this one is simplest. Although you do get that *if*

```
public static void Foo<T>(this T objectC)
     where T: C
{
     if(typeof(T)==typeof(B){ //or for runtime check:     if(objectC is B)
          //specific
     }
}
```

you could then call Foo on any instance of A or B.

You mention you don´t want if statements, but I'm not sure to which extend you're trying to avoid that? The only way to completely avoid it, is to have 2 extension methods, one for A and one for B, (which in turn can call a common method for C), but I think you're trying to avoid multiple extension methods?

**edit** If you absolutely want to prevent if's, you'll have to use multiple extension methods as shown in Frederik's post. You could add an extension for the baseclass as well, that only gets called if the type is not known during compilation. But that would still need an if ;)

```
public static void Foo(this A a)
{
}

public static void Foo(this B b)
{
}

public static void Foo(this C c)
{
    if(c is A)
       Foo((A)c);
    else if(c is B)
       Foo((B)c);
    else
       throw new NotSupportedException(c.GetType().FullName);
}
```

If the type is always known at compile time, you can simply use the 2 extension methods for A en B.

Comment: I think this is the most pragmatic solution.  I agree that the *if* is a bit ugly but it's either that or use multiple extension methods.  A purist might opt for a Decorator pattern implementation that uses a factory to create decorator types and that might be appropriate if you're building a framework that needs to be extensible in an Open-Closed-Principle way (the extension method way violates OCP)

Comment: I do not want to use if statements because I think that comparing runtime types is not a good practise :)

Comment: It's a little late to worry about good practice. How else can you tell A from B without looking at their types?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
public static class CExtensions {
     public static void DoIt( this B foo ) {}

     public static void DoIt( this A foo ) {}
}
```

But, I don't think that this will work:

```
C x = new A();
x.DoIt();
```

I don't think it will compile, but, I can't test it right now.

Answer (score 0):

Purely from a feasibility point of view, it is possible using reflection and extension methods. Whether it makes sense in the context of your application, is something you should judge. Here goes the solution....

```
class C
{
}

class A : C
{
}

class B : C
{
}

static class Extender
{
    public static void M(this B b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" Extension method on B");
    }

    public static void M(this A a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" Extension method on A");
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        C c = new A();// The actual instance here will be created using some factory.
        object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(c.GetType());
        Type typeToFind = c.GetType();

        Type typeToQuery = typeof(Extender);

        var query = from method in typeToQuery.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static
                        | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                    where method.IsDefined(typeof(ExtensionAttribute), false)
                    where method.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == typeToFind
                    select method;
      // You would be invoking the method based on its name. This is just a quick demo. 
        foreach (MethodInfo m in query)
        {
            m.Invoke(instance, new object[] { instance });
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To me this feels like a flaw in design.
If you can't have a common class to two sub classes which override and changes functionality without knowing the run time type you clearly have some issues with the overall design.

Should that functionality that differ depending on run time types really reside in those classes at all?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way. Create a class with the different methods you need. In the same class define a delegate with the signature of this methods and keep a Dictionary where the keys are the types, and the values the delegates. Finally you can create an extension method for your class C that look into the dictionary using the type of the object that's executing the method itself and executes the right method. Something like this:

```
public static class CExtender
{
    private static void DoItA(C anA)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("A");
    }

    private static void DoItB(C aB)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("B");
    }

    private static void DoItC(C aC)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("C");
    }

    delegate void DoItDel(C aC);

    private static Dictionary<Type, DoItDel> _doItDels;

    private static Dictionary<Type, DoItDel> DoItDels
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_doItDels == null)
            {
                _doItDels = new Dictionary<Type, DoItDel>();
                _doItDels[typeof(A)] = new DoItDel(DoItA);
                _doItDels[typeof(B)] = new DoItDel(DoItB);
            }
            return _doItDels; 
        }
    }

    // the only public part is the extension method
    public static void DoIt(this C aC)
    {
        DoItDel aDel;
        if (DoItDels.TryGetValue(aC.GetType(), out aDel))
            aDel(aC);
        else
            DoItC(aC);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Decorater pattern** in this case.

i.e. you can have 2 new classes of your own let say A1, B1 both deriving from C. (provided C is not a sealed class. If that's the case solution would be a bit different). Also A1 and B1 needs to wrap A and B corespondingly. You could inject instances of A and B through the constructors of A1 and B1.

You can also have a common interface which A1 and B1 both implmement. Interface needs to have the method which you need A1 and B1 to implement in their own ways. (A1 and B1 can delegate the calls to A or B as needed)

This way, in your client code, you can refer to A1 and B1 instances by their interface type and perform the common operation defined in the interface without knowing what their actual concrete implementations are.

Let me know if you need a code sample if I wasn't clear.

Comment: But how I can know which of the types (A1 or A2) is needed co be created? It is known only at runtime.